# update problem in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, ppa

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get the following output. As you can see that there are error messages at the end 'configured multiple times'. How do I solve it. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Hit:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease       
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu bionic Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:4
```

Comment: So what should I do

Answer (score 1):

Remove your octave ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt update
```

To install octave in 18.04, you can run:

```
sudo apt install octave
```

[It's available in bionic (18.04)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/octave)

Comment: Well how do I install octave then

Comment: [bionic has octave package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/octave). just type `sudo apt install octave` in your terminal, sir

Comment: I followed the commands but still I am getting the same output

Comment: I followed the commands but still I am facing the same issue